# WooCommerce Change Attribute slug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slug

i have an issue in Woocommerce 2.5.5, I have stored the products attributes already on Woo and the site is in production, but i am using Greek for my site, and all the Slugs of attributes where stored in DB with wrong encoding, causing trouble in my ways. An example is

%ce%bc%ce%b7%ce%bd%cf%8e%ce%bd - Μηνών (which is "month" in English, this should be stored as "minon" or "μηνων") using the auto slug creator of WP.

Now i want to change the attribute  slug of "Age", but there are almost 4000 products that will lose that property if i change it. Is there any way, or plugin to change it to the whole database? Otherwise, woul i be able to change all of them using find/replace all using a text editor?

Comment: The original plugin for that is [Search & Replace](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) since 2011. The other one mentioned in the answer below, is just a clone (2015) of this original one. So @E.Agolli is right when he says that making a backup before is strongly recommended… within your database, with this kind of plugin, you could make searches and bulk stunning fast replaces with ease, without any skills related to the database ops and names... Let us know…

Comment: That's something i can do with search and replace in a text editor, which i have done. I downloaded the dump, open it in mysql workbench and Search&Replace everything, when i uploaded the db, all the registered attributes in configurable products were lost.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin Should help you [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) . I have used before and it worked for me. But you have to be carefully to always make a backup of your site and database to restore it in any case. To use the plugin you should know the column that you want to make the changes.